# Remap Shift_R+Enter to Enter, but leave Shift_L+Enter alone

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xmodmap

Sometimes I'll clumsily hit both the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, resulting in a <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> by accident.  If I *want* to type <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> I'll use the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.  So I'd like to remap <kbd>Shift_R+Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Enter</kbd> but leave <kbd>Shift_L+Enter</kbd> as <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>.  I've looked over `xmodmap` but can't figure out how to get it to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that easyly, because what is interpreted is the **modifier Shift** + the keysym <kbd>enter</kbd>, and the **modifier Shift** cannot do the distinction between the keysyms <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> and <kbd>Shift_L</kbd>.

A solution is to define two separate modifiers with `xkb` (xmodmap is useless here) for <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> and <kbd>Shift_L</kbd>; then redefine **ALL** of the «types» definitions you use in */usr/share/X11/xkb/types* to accept the two distinct modifiers as the same layer, and keep a custom one only for your <kbd>space</kbd> so only one shift will trigger the second layer on it.

Eventually because you have now a non regular modifier for your second shift, some applications will stop to intrepret it correctly (shifted selection).